# NSString: dealing with UTF8-based API

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring

Which characterset is the default characterset for NSString, when i get typed content from a UITextField?

I developed an app, which sends such NSStrings to a UTF8-based REST-API. At the backend, there is an utf8 based MySQL-Database and also utf8-based varchar-fields.
My POST-Request sends string data from the iOS App to the server. And with a GET-Request i receive those strings from the REST API.

Within the App, everything is printed fine. Special UTF-8-Characters like ÄÖÜ are showed correctly after sending them to the server and after receive them back.

But when i enter the mysql-console of the server of the REST API, and do a SELECT-Command at these data, there are broken characters visible.

What could be the root cause? In which characterset does Apple use a NSString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like it is a server issue. Check that the version you are using supports UTF-8, older versions do not. See : [How to support full Unicode in MySQL database](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)

MySQL’s utf8 encoding is different from proper UTF-8 encoding. It doesn’t offer full Unicode support.

MySQL 5.5.3 (released in early 2010) introduced a new encoding called utf8mb4 which maps to proper UTF-8 and thus fully supports Unicode.

NSString has in internal representation that is essentially opaque.

The `UITextField` method `text` returns an `NSString`.

When you want data from a string use to send to a server use `- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding` and specify the encoding such as `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

```
NSData *textFieldUTF8Data = [textFieldInstance.text dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: utf8mb4, as its name implies, adds 4-byte utf8 characters.  Those occur in a few Chinese characters, some new emoticons, and a few other situations.  If you are not using any of those, then utf8mb4 is not relevant.

Comment: The 4-byte UTF-8 characters are more than "a few Chinese characters, some new emoticons." The majority of the emoji characters are in plane-1 and require 4 bytes for UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoding. The issue is that MySQL only allocated 3 bytes to their non-standard "utf8" and named it as if it supported UTF-8–"bad MySQL". This worked until characters were put in plane-1. UTF-8 is one to four bytes. Note that the user in many cases is the one who is using the emoji and other plane-1 characters, not supporting them is both short-sighted and restricting the users.

Answer (score 0):

If, by "mysql console", you are referring to the DOS-like window in Windows, then you need:

The command "chcp" controls the "code page". chcp 65001 provides utf8, but it needs a special charset installed, too. some code pages
To set the font in the console window: Right-click on the title of the window → Properties → Font → pick Lucida Console

Also, tell the 'console' that your bytes are UTF8 by doing `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.

Comment: i am working an a MAC and connected via SSH to the servers terminal

Comment: Sorry, I don't know whether "terminal" is already utf8-savvy.  And if it is not, how to make it so.  Still you need `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.